# Htaccess and tilde (~) redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm helping a friend moving an website from one server to another. 
Right now it doesn't have a domain name, so to test the things i have an url like this:
http://ip_address/~sitename

The original site, in the html folder has a private and public folders, every request that the server receives must be redirected to a file with the same name but in the public folder.

The problem it's that I can't make the .htaccess redirects to work.

I began with a simple test that worked fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~samplesite/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~samplesite/public/redirect.html [NC,L]
```

So every request the site receive will show this redirct.html page.

Now when i try to change to make the correct redirects, it gives me 404, what I already tested:

```
RewriteRule ^~samplesite/?(.*)$ /~samplesite/public/redirect.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)samplesite(.*)/?$ /~samplesite/public/redirect.html [NC,L]
```

The second one it's to map the **~samplesite** to the correct folder strucutture that exists on the server **/home/samplesite/public_html**

I don't know if I missing something here, any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, using the R=302 I came to the conclusion that the ~samplesite was in the REQUEST_URI, so it doesn't get tested in the RewriteRule.

How I tested:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~samplesite/public/redirect.html?=%{REQUEST_URI}&?=$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

Final rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~samplesite/public/$1 [NC,L]
```